# Как с помощью .htaccess выдать 404 ошибку или закрыть доступ к директориям на сайте?

Tags: http-status-code-404, .htaccess, php

Как с помощью .htaccess выдать 404 ошибку или закрыть доступ к директориям на сайте?

```
Disallow: /dir
Disallow: /321
Disallow: /news
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно вернуть код 404 через `RewriteRule`, но работает не на всех версиях Apache (в v.2.4.10 работает)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(dir|321|news)
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```